# Не могу передать пустой параметр в http get запросе

Tags: typescript, http, angular

есть текстбокс с фио

```
 [(ngModel)]="fio"
```

определяю его в компоненте

```
fio: string="";
```

хочу передать в hhtp get введенное значение и null, если ничего не вписано

```
let param = new HttpParams();

param = param.append('DateIn', this.DateIn.toDateString())
.append('DateOut', this.DateOut.toDateString())
.append('fio', this.fio);

this.http.get<EventLog[]>(this.BaseUrl +'EventLog/FromPeriod',{params: param})
.subscribe(result_per => {this.EventLogs = result_per;}, error => console.error(error));
```

при загрузке пишет ошибку BadRequest, параметры вывел в консоли, фио - пустая строка, что и логично.

```
PARAMS= DateIn=Mon%20Jan%2023%202023&DateOut=Wed%20Jan%2025%202023&fio=
```

Может ошибка в контроллере на API?

```
 public IEnumerable<EventLog> Get([FromQuery] DateTime DateIn,
                                     [FromQuery] DateTime DateOut,                                         
                                     [FromQuery] string fio)
```

Как обработать передачу fio если оно не прописано в текстбокс?

Comment: `.append('fio', this.fio || 'какой то текст, который надо обработать как отсутствие фио')`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov я пробовал `this.fio || ''` - не сработало, вариант 'null' не подходит

Comment: Http query parameter это по определению строка. Можно на сервере научиться отличать случаи когда передано `name=` от случая когда вообще ничего не передали. Но этот очень ненадёжный способ.

Comment: @CreatureFear что null, что пустая строка приравнивается к отсутствию значения. Отправьте какой нибудь `'unauthorized_user'` если уж надо что-то отправить

Comment: @DmitryKozlov и на сервере присваивать null?

Comment: @CreatureFear угу